# JuiceUI not working with ScriptManager AjaxFrameworkMode disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager, juice-ui

I'm using [JuiceUI](http://juiceui.com/) library in my project and I found that its components doesn't work when there is `AjaxFrameworkMode=Disabled` on the `ScriptManager`. **My question is, why?** I was told that I want this property disabled in newer projects (read asp.net 4.5). Althought, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew) a try, might resolve the issue. It's a close cousin of Juice UI.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, but solves the problem.